# Rails error on respond_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, respond-to

i have create a simple user authentication for learning Rails:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def new
     @user = User.new
   end

   def create
     respond_to do |format|
        if @user.save
           format.hmtl {redirect_to root_url}
        else
           format.hmtl {render 'new'}
        end
    end
 end
```

If i create a new user without the block respond_to and format.html all works fine (in the db i have the created user and the page is redirected).
With this code, the user is created but i have the following error (and i don't have the redirection):

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 218ms

NameError (uninitialized constant Mime::HMTL):
   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:16:in `block in create'
   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:14:in `create'
```

P.S: i want the respond_to and format because after i want add the format.json method

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo - change `format.hmtl` to `format.html`

Comment: sorry i don't have understand what i must change...can u explain it please?

Comment: In your code, you have mixed up the letters `html` with `hmtl` - which, of course, isn't the mime type you are looking for.  Unless you are using HyperMarkup Text Language...